# Custom checkout field that remove cart items taxes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a custom checkout field in WooCommerce. The current configuration is such that if this field is empty, cart items tax is enabled. However, I want the tax to be set to "zero" when this field is populated.

Despite implementing some code to achieve this, it hasn't worked as expected. For instance, on one of the orders where the tax should have been zero, my code set it to $2.78 instead. Can anyone assist me in rectifying this?

Here is my PHP code:

```php
//custom to remove code
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_field($checkout) {
    echo '<div id="custom-checkout-field">';
    woocommerce_form_field('no_tax_field', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array('input-text'),
        'label' => __('Custom No Tax Field'),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter something to remove tax'),
    ), $checkout->get_value('no_tax_field'));
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_woocommerce_checkout_field');

function custom_woocommerce_recalculate_tax($cart) {
    
    //if (isset($_POST['no_tax_field']) && !empty($_POST['no_tax_field'])) {
        foreach ($cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $value) {
            $value['data']->set_tax_class('zero-rate');
        }
    //}
    //and one problem here this code to set tax class not working isset($_POST['no_tax_field']) . Please check this also.if i remove this isset if condition then this code run every time on load of checout page.
     
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_woocommerce_recalculate_tax', 10, 1);

function handle_custom_field_ajax() {
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_field_change', 'handle_custom_field_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_field_change', 'handle_custom_field_ajax');
```

The jQuery code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document.body).on('change', '#no_tax_field', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://thevacdaddy.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                'action': 'custom_field_change',
                'value': $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I've introduced a new custom field on the checkout page in WordPress. The current configuration is such that if this field is empty, the tax shows up. However, I want the tax to be set to zero when this field is populated. Despite implementing some code to achieve this, it hasn't worked as expected. For instance, on one of the orders where the tax should have been zero, my code set it to $2.78 instead. Can anyone assist me in rectifying this?